# Fast aggregate matrix by column and row groups

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate

I have a big matrix `mat` with rownames `group_label_x` and colnames `group_label_y`. I want to aggregate `mat` into `ave_mat`, by `group_label_x` and `group_label_y`, where the value of `ave_mat[i,j]` is the average value of `mat[ group_label_x[i], group_label_y[j] ]`. This can be achieved using a double forloop, or applying twice the `aggregate` function (`aggregate( mat, by = list(group_label_x), FUN='mean' )`). But is there any approach that can achieve faster speed? (since I have many matrices to aggregate).

The following code generates a demo random matrix of approximately 1E4 rows and 2E4 cols, which I want to aggregate into a ~1E3 x 1E3 matrix:

```
set.seed(1)

dim_x_raw = 1E4
dim_y_raw = 2E4

n_groups_x = 1E3
n_groups_y = 1E3

group_len_x = diff(sort(sample( 1:dim_x_raw, n_groups_x )))
group_label_x = rep( paste0('group_', 1:length(group_len_x)), group_len_x )

group_len_y = diff(sort(sample( 1:dim_y_raw, n_groups_y )))
group_label_y = rep( paste0('group_', 1:length(group_len_y)), group_len_y )

mat = matrix( runif( length(group_label_x)*length(group_label_y) ), length(group_label_x) )

######################################
```

My aggreagation code (which is slow):

```
ave_mat_x = aggregate( mat, by = list(group_label_x), FUN='mean' )
ave_mat = aggregate( t(ave_mat_x), by = list(group_label_y), FUN='mean' )
```

Comment: can u try with dplyr package? generally `data.table` and `tidyverse` are very fast in r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
# add row and colnames
mat = matrix(runif( length(group_label_x)*length(group_label_y)), length(group_label_x), 
              dimnames = list(group_label_x, group_label_y))
# transform to data.table
mat_dt <- data.table(mat, keep.rownames = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rm(mat) #rmove the old matrix
# melt, summarise per group and calculate mean
mat_dt <- melt(mat_dt, id.vars = "rn")
head(mat_dt)
        rn variable     value
1: group_1  group_1 0.8718050
2: group_1  group_1 0.9671970
3: group_1  group_1 0.8669163
4: group_1  group_1 0.4377153
5: group_1  group_1 0.1919378
6: group_1  group_1 0.0822944
res <- mat_dt[,.(Mean=mean(value)),.(rn, variable)]
head(res)
        rn variable      Mean
1: group_1  group_1 0.4888935
2: group_2  group_1 0.3903115
3: group_3  group_1 0.4601481
4: group_4  group_1 0.5023852
5: group_5  group_1 0.5067483
6: group_6  group_1 0.4851856
dim(res)
[1] 998001      3
```

Of course you can run all in one line and check the speed

```
system.time(
 res <- melt(data.table(mat, keep.rownames = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), id.vars = "rn")[,.(Mean=mean(value)),.(rn, variable)]
+ )
       User      System verstrichen 
       8.15        0.01        8.19
```

Comment: Then, is there a function to convert res into a matrix ave_mat, where ave_mat[i,j] is the average value of mat[ group_label_x[i], group_label_y[j] ]? Indeed, I was not able to retrieve res[[2]], which gave me an error: Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor. Using the method dcast(res, rn ~ variable, value.var="Mean") will also give this error